# Элементы RecyclerView меняются при обновлении

Tags: android, request

Есть список городов, прохожу по нему, считываю из него город и дальше отправляю запрос и получаю результат.

Однако периодически список городов меняет порядок, проходил дебаггером медленно все ок, если быстро, то список уже получается меняется случайным образом, я так подозреваю что дело в том что когда запрос добавляется в очередь запросов volley, то ответ приходит не сразу и получается такая беда.. подскажите в чем ошибка? как исправить?

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    weatherList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    cityListAdapter = new CityListAdapter(getActivity(), weatherList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cityListAdapter);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            getCityTemp();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void getCityTemp() {
    weatherList.clear();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    MyApplication.getInstance().getDb().getAllCityAsync(new DataBaseHelper.DatabaseHand<List<Weather>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(boolean success, final List<Weather> result) {
            if (success) {
                for (final Weather cn : result) {
                    String url = CITY_TEMP_URL + cn.location.getCity() + METRIC + API_KEY;
                    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            try {
                                MyApplication.getInstance().setWeather(
                                        JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(jsonObject.toString(), cn.getId()));
                                weatherList.add(MyApplication.getInstance().getWeather());
                                cityListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                        }
                    });
                    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, cn.getId());
                }
            }
            MyApplication.getInstance().getDb().close();
        }
    });
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: проблема в том, что вы циклом запускаете n-oe количество потоков new JsonObjectRequest, что в свою очередь не гарантируют ту же самую последовательность получения ответа в onResponce.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид как можно выйти из данной ситуации?  я пробовал поставил listener onFinish встроенного в volley, однако это не привело к желаемому результату, или же я его не верно использовал.